# Change the colors of a bar histogram in Scilab

Tags: bar-chart, scilab

I have a 40*2 matrix and I want to represent it in a bar format in SCILAB.
And i want the data to be stacked.

So I checked and used the bar function, and for now it goes like this :

```
bar(Data,'stacked');
```

[image: stacked bar histogram for a 40*2 matrix in green and blue]

I want to customize the color of the graph by giving differents pairs of colors for each bar of the plot.

I tried to use a "vector of M strings" like suggested on the scilab help, but it takes into account only the first two colors specified, as I expected.

```
bar(Data,['yellow','red','cyan,'black'],'stacked']
```

[image: stacked bar histogram for a 40*2 matrix, in red and yellow]

Does anyone here might have a clue as to how I can do that ?
Thanks a lot in advance

EDIT : So thanks to S. Gougeon i can do it. But now I want to use the barh() function instead of the bar().
I tried to change only the bar by barh, but obviously it didn't work.
I tried then to do it with a single bar :

```
y=[40 60]; barh(1,y,'stacked');
```

I get the following image and these warning messages :
WARNING: Transposing row vector Y to get compatible dimensions
WARNING: Transposing data matrix Y to get compatible dimensions
[image: bar chart with one horizontal bar that goes from 40 to 100]

I don't know why I have those warnings, since it's correctly working with bar(); and there is no difference in the help for the barh() function.
Moreover there is only the second data on the chart, and I still don't know why.

Comment: What you want to do with "cyan" and "black" along the 40 bars, in addition to "red" and "yellow",  is unclear. Do you want one bar over 2 being cyan+black instead of yellow+red? Or what else?

Comment: Yes that was the idea. I want to have bar 1 in yellow+red, bar 2 in cyan+black, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `barh()` issues:

- please note that warnings have already been [reported](https://bugzilla.scilab.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&order=resolution%2Cbug_id%20DESC&product=Scilab%20software&query_format=advanced&short_desc=%28%5E%7C%5B%5Ea-zA-Z_%5D%29%28barh%29%28%5B%5E0-9a-zA-Z_%3B%5D%7C%24%29&short_desc_type=regexp).
- do not hesitate to report the bad display

This one can be worked around by using bar(), and then rotate the axes by 90°:

```
gca().rotation_angles(2) = 0;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the pair of colors for any bar to the next one, you have to plot the bars one by one. Here is an example:

```
clf
n = 30;
colors = ["blue" "magenta" "green" "cyan" "red" "yellow" "pink" "linen" "bisque" "scilabcyan3" "lavender" "deepskyblue" "slateblue" "skyblue" "turquoise" "palegreen" "white" "scilabmagenta3" "scilabbrown2" "scilabpink4" "khaki" "indianred"];
C = colors(grand(n,2,"uin", 1,size(colors,"*")));

y = rand(1,n)*100;
y = [y ; 100-y]';
drawlater
for i = 1:n
    bar(i, y(i,:), 0.8, C(i,:), "stacked");
end
gca().x_ticks = tlist(["ticks" "locations" "labels"],1:n, string(1:n));
gca().tight_limits(1) = "on";
drawnow
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example, it's been super useful to me. If by any chance you know how to do it with barh() also, it'd be great, because when i try to do it with this method the error message says that there is a problem with the dimension of x and y; x being only one number.